# ngrx - update value in nested object

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot assign to read only property 'active' of object '[object Object]'
```

I know that the message means, I can't work on the state directly. Overall i'm trying to switch a boolean. my reducer is

```js
on(ConfigsActions.toggle, (state, data) => {
    const clone = getAllConfigs.projector();
    const conf = clone.find(f => f.id === data.config.id);
          conf.domains.forEach(domain => {
              domain.features.forEach(feature => {
                if(feature.settingId === data.setting.settingId) {
                  feature.active = !feature.active;
                }
                else {
                  feature.components.forEach(component => {
                    if(component.settingId === data.setting.settingId) {
                      component.active = !component.active;
                    }
                  })
                }
              })
            }
          );

    return configsAdapter.updateOne({id: conf.id, changes: {
      domains: conf.domains
    }}, state);
  })
```

What am I doing wrong? Maybe the reducer is not where I should make those changes?

Comment: You are mutating the objects. You need to return a new object and overwrite the value that needs to be updated. e.g.: `return { ...state, /* update whatever needs updating */}` Or for a nested object: `return { ...state, nestedObject: {...nestedObject, /* update value here*/}}`.

Comment: isn't "clone" a new object? In my knowledge that should work.

Comment: Isn't `clone` a reference to the original slice of state ? I'm not sure though.

Comment: It's not clear from the code sample if `clone` is a new object. If you're getting a read-only assignment error, it's highly unlikely that it's a new, unfrozen object.

Comment: i get it.  gonna go and refactor a bit of code now.

Answer (score 1):

State in the NgRx store is immutable. You're mutating it directly, which gives this error (because the Object is frozen). https://ngrx.io/guide/store/configuration/runtime-checks#strictstateimmutability

Instead, create a clone, or use the rest operator to mutate state.
You can also take a look at [ngrx-immer](https://github.com/timdeschryver/ngrx-immer) which makes this easy. With it, you can simply mutate the state in a "normal way".